# Can [on-topic] and [scope] be merged and synonymised?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, meta

The [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag is for questions about the scope of the site. That includes questions about what kind of things are [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) or [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic), but there have already been four questions using the [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) tag, three of them *without* using the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag.

**Please can [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) be merged and synonymised with [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)?**

I know I could just retag those questions manually, but a synonymisation would enable people to choose the right tag when typing `topic` into the tag box on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Done.](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope/synonyms)

Thanks @Robert!